# Why in ZedGraph the Y axis is very small?

Tags: c#

I have this ZedGraph control code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ZedGraph;
using Extracting_Frames;

namespace Lightnings_Extractor
{
    public partial class Histogram_Graphs : Form
    {

        public long[] histogram;

        public Histogram_Graphs()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            histogram = Form1.GetHistogramValue;
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            CreateGraph_GradientByZBars(zedGraphControl1);

        }

        private void Histogram_Graphs_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void CreateGraph_GradientByZBars(ZedGraphControl z1)
        {
            GraphPane myPane = z1.GraphPane;
            myPane.Title.Text = "Demonstration of Multi-Colored Bars with a Single BarItem";
            myPane.XAxis.Title.Text = "Bar Number";
            myPane.YAxis.Title.Text = "Value";

            PointPairList list = new PointPairList();
            Random rand = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < histogram.Length; i++)
            {
                double x = (double)i + 1;
                //double y = (double)i + 1;//rand.NextDouble() * 1000;
                double z = i / 4.0;
                list.Add(x, histogram[i], z);
            }

            BarItem myCurve = myPane.AddBar("Multi-Colored Bars", list, Color.Blue);
            Color[] colors = { Color.Red, Color.Yellow, Color.Green, Color.Blue, Color.Purple };
            myCurve.Bar.Fill = new Fill(colors);
            myCurve.Bar.Fill.Type = FillType.GradientByZ;

            myCurve.Bar.Fill.RangeMin = 0;
            myCurve.Bar.Fill.RangeMax = 4;

            myPane.Chart.Fill = new Fill(Color.White, Color.FromArgb(220, 220, 255), 45);
            myPane.Fill = new Fill(Color.White, Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 225), 45);
            // Tell ZedGraph to calculate the axis ranges
            z1.AxisChange();
        } 
    }
}
```

The problem is in the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < histogram.Length; i++)
                {
                    double x = (double)i + 1;
                    //double y = (double)i + 1;//rand.NextDouble() * 1000;
                    double z = i / 4.0;
                    list.Add(x, histogram[i], z);
                }
```

Befote Y was random. Now i want to use the values in the histogram List.
So for example in index[0] there is a number: 34118 then in index[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L54q5.jpg) 1521 index[2] 522
There are 256 indexs in the List.

When i see the Graph is see the bard height very very short.

In the beginning of the graph i see one line very high but all the next lines are very short.
And on the Y axis i see on the side numbers start from 0 to 40 and on the x axis i see numbers from 0 to 300.

On the axis Y i should see numbers from 0 to the highest value in the histogram i guess and on the axis X i should see from 0 to 256.

Big mess here.

How should i fix it ?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I think it has more to do with representation of your `list` where you are drawing the bars. Put a breakpoint at `BarItem myCurve = myPane.AddBar(` and see what are the values in `list`

Comment: nawfal i did. And what i see is: In the list in index 0 i see: {(1,34118)} in index 1 i see {(2,1251)} and so on untill 256.

Comment: Im addin an image to my question about how the ZedGraph looks like.

Comment: Those are very high values. If you cant reproduce that to the graph, then the issue is where u r drawing it, isnt it?

Comment: Im not sure nawfal where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

There's no bug in your code. Your graph is accurately drawing the values that are in your `histogram[]` array.

You mention that your array contains the following values:

```
histogram[0] = 34118
histogram[1] = 1521
histogram[2] = 522
...
```

If you inspect your screenshot, the plots are correct. The very first bar drawn is quite tall, and the other remaining values (to your expectations) are close to the 1x10^3 band. It is likely that your `histogram[]` array is being initialized with the wrong data, or faulty data at index `[0]`.

I can only provide speculation about the significance of the value in at `histogram[0]` from this side of your code and data, but perhaps you are receiving an array that has the sum of all of the remaining data in index `[0]`.

As a quick check of expectations, if you change your loop to start from index `[1]` instead of `[0]`, you will see that the plot control you are using will perform correctly for all the other values that are expected to be near the 1x10^3 band, and you should check the data source that fills your `histogram` array to see if that first data point is relevant or has been set to an erroneous value.

```
for (int i = 1; i < histogram.Length; i++)
{
    double x = (double)i + 1;
    //double y = (double)i + 1;//rand.NextDouble() * 1000;
    double z = i / 4.0;
    list.Add(x, histogram[i], z);
}
```